# Qemu versions/branches?

Tags: qemu

I have searched the net, but to no avail.

Why is there 0.x and 1.x branches for Qemu, both maintained and kicking ?
What's the difference between the two ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upstream is: http://repo.or.cz/w/qemu.git

I don't see the 0.15 branch being maintained. The version after 0.15 was 1.0. Why did they call it 1.0 instead of 0.16? I don't know. Where do you see the older branch being "maintained and kicking"?

Comment: But 1.0 was released _after_ 0.15.1. I see no indication of the 0.15 branch being alive after 1.0 was released. I see no indication anyone plans for 0.15.2.